# Table tr td cant get text in one lane

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to build a newsletter for an email campaign. I have to build it with tables and all that cause most of the email clients ignore thinks like div etc. now I have the problem that I would like to have the text obertauern ...... in one line and under it the line ( `<hr>` ) but its not working the way I would like to have it.

On the pic you can see what I'm trying to do and I put the html into jsfiddle.

```
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
 <td colspan="2">
 <a href="http://www.salzburgerland.com/de/ski-board/index.html?utm_campaign=RK_WI_13&utm_medium=DE&utm_source=CARE-Verlag&utm_content=Newsletter" target="_blank"><img src="head.jpg" width="700" border="0"></a>
 </td>

          <tr> 
          <td colspan="2">
            <p style="color:#00668a;text-align:left;font-size:18px;">
Wer den Sonnenskilauf im SalzburgerLand  noch intensiv genießen möchte, den erwarten strahlender Sonnenschein, bestens präparierte Pisten und sensationelle Urlaubsangebote:

</p></td>
        </tr>

<tr style="background-color:#deeef4;">

<td width="130" cellpadding="0" ><p style="color:#00668a;padding:10px">OBERTAUERN <span style="color:#a9a9a9;font-size:13px">Gültigkeit der Pauschale: 22.03. – 12.04.2014 & 19.04. – 04.05.2014</span></p><a href="http://urlaub.salzburgerland.com/de/winterurlaub?utm_campaign=RK_WI_13&utm_medium=DE&utm_source=CARE-Verlag&utm_content=Newsletter" target="_blank">
<img src="ab1.jpg" width="250" height="138" border="0" style="padding:10px"></a>


<td width="200" height="163"><p>"Sund and Fun Wochen"</p>

<ul>
<li>7 Tage Aufenhthalt inkl. Frühstück</li>
<li>7 Tage Aufenhthalt inkl. Frühstück</li>
</ul><img src="button.png" width="345" height="35" border="0"></td></td>


</tr>

</table>
```

[image: pic]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mSLf4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the border property to create the line and change the p to a div so you do not put a lot of space after it:

```
<tr> 
      <td colspan="2">
        <div style="border-top: solid 1px #00668a;height:1px;">
```

Here is a jFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qXxPb/2/

Comment: thanks. but how do i get the text in one line just like in the pic . ps. i updated the jsfiddle

Comment: i updated the jsfiddle now . so now u can see it with pix. 

here u can see how it should look like http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=35je0t2&s=8#.UvOKlbS4uzo

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<td width="600" cellpadding="0" >
```

For the td where the text is located (or use something else than 600).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mSLf4/5/

Should work like that, you missed some tablecells and I made your sentence in an extra row + set the cell to span over 2 cells.

Should work now, next time validate your code first please.

```
<td colspan="2">...</td>
```

was the important line.

Comment: could u tell me how i could give the blue background a radius ? just like in the pic.

Comment: In general, this works by adding `border-radius` as a style to the element

Comment: there is a nother problem . if u could take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/mSLf4/7/  . the turkis button is not on the same height with the pink box and the text sund and fun should be on the height from the pic . just like here. and how do i get space between the line and the box http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=35je0t2&s=8#.UvON6rS4uzp